# Animating css tabs using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have css tabs,i am trying to get fadein effect when a tab is clicked

I found 1 [tutorial](http://jsfiddle.net/kw3cq/) on the web to animate css tabs,however i dont want to change my css,etc.I copy pasted the jquery code and made necessary changes

Here is what i have tried so far
http://jsfiddle.net/McZV9/8/

The issue is,when i reclick the tabs,the content disappears.Can anyone help me please.

Here the code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ul class="tabs clearfix">
    <li><a href="#html" class="current">HTML</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#javascript">JavaScript</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#css">CSS</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
    <div class="current" id="html">grtgrtgrtg</div>
    <div id="javascript">erfefr</div>
    <div id="css">
        <p>Similar to the the CSS is used to style the tooltip, or info box.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
  function resetTabs() {
        $(".content > div").hide(); //Hide all content
        $(".tabs a").attr("class", ""); //Reset id's      
    }

    var myUrl = window.location.href; //get URL
    var myUrlTab = myUrl.substring(myUrl.indexOf(".")); // For localhost/tabs.html#tab2, myUrlTab = .tab2     
    var myUrlTabName = myUrlTab.substring(0, 4); // For the above example, myUrlTabName = #tab

    (function () {
        $(".content > div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
        $(".tabs li:first a").attr("class", "current"); // Activate first tab
        $(".content > div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

        $(".tabs a").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).attr("id") == "current") { //detection for current tab
                return
            } else {
                resetTabs();
                $(this).attr("class", "current"); // Activate this
                $($(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
            }
        });

        for (i = 1; i <= $(".tabs li").length; i++) {
            if (myUrlTab == myUrlTabName + i) {
                resetTabs();
                $("a[name='" + myUrlTab + "']").attr("id", "current"); // Activate url tab
                $(myUrlTab).fadeIn(); // Show url tab content        
            }
        }
    })()
```

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your code and it works perfectly now:

```
(function () {

    $(".tabs a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var hash = $(this).attr('href');
        window.location.hash = 'tab-' + hash.replace('#', '');

        if ($(this).hasClass("current")) { //detection for current tab
            return;
        } else {
            $(".content > div").hide();
            $(".tabs a").removeClass("current");
            $(this).addClass("current"); // Activate this
            $(hash).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
        }
    });

    $(".tabs li:first a").trigger('click'); // Activate first tab

    if(window.location.hash != ''){
        $('.tabs a[href="'+window.location.hash.replace('tab-', '')+'"]').trigger('click');
    }

})();
```

Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/McZV9/14/

Comment: Thanks a lot...i am confused...whom should i give the best answer...both worked?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly..

Why do you want to replace the class using `.attr()` when you have access to `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` methods.

Your main issue was this line

```
$($(this).attr('name')).fadeIn();
```

Supposed to be

```
$($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/McZV9/15/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot...i am confused...whom should i give the best answer...both worked?

Comment: haha.. It is your call and you can mark the post that provided you with a better solution for the problem